# I Have Some Problems in codeigniter with sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I try to check when someone logged in his/her account show the page with the session, I loaded session in libraries but the session doesn't work
And Sorry For My Bad English 
Thanks For The Help :)

**This Is The Model**

```
class login_model extends CI_Model
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function check()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $remember = $this->input->post('remember');

    $this->db->select('username','password');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('username',$username);
    $this->db->where('password',md5($password));

    $result = $this->db->count_all_results();

    if($result > 0)
    {
        $data_session = array(
            'username'=>$username,
            'islogin'=>true,    
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
        redirect('post/index');
    }
```

**This Is The Controller**

```
class Post extends CI_Controller
{
public function index()
{

    $login = $this->session->userdata('islogin');

    if($login == true)
    {
        $data = array (
            'name' => 'Hello',
        );
        $this->load->view('post/index',$data);
    }
    else {
        redirect('login/index');
    }

}
}
```

**This Is The Config**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'weblogdata';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 3600;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'tbl_ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;

$config['encryption_key'] = m.D~wt,wA:MjS9$]g<H4Z7eW.7`0vDbX$F`LUgCg+>$1?0L$vq1:7vaVf&d{U(
```

Comment: hint: `'islogin'=>true` vs `$this->session->userdata('login');`

Comment: i did this but still doesn't work

Comment: **Warning!** Never store passwords in clear text! Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Ok , Thanks For The Tips

Comment: Could you show me the result of var_dump($_SESSION)?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a valid problem statement here. also, an no offense, but you should consider using ion_auth instead of rolling your own system.

Comment: @VanTho Here : array(3) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1542973990) ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["islogin"]=> bool(true) }

Comment: I Think Problem Is, Model Not Send Session In Post Page, I Used Var_Dump in Post Controller And Result Is : array(1) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1542974240) }

Answer (score 0):

set your session condition on contruct(), change the controller to be like this :

```
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
        if($this->session->userdata('islogin') != true)
        {
            redirect('login/index');
        }
}

function index() {
        $data = array (
        'name' => 'Hello',
    );
    $this->load->view('post/index',$data);
}
```

Comment: That Doesn't Work :(

Comment: The Problem Is When I Redirect To Post Controller Session Will Destroy And Doesn't Save In the browser

Comment: what do you mean save in the browser? in your config, you used to save session in DB

Comment: When I redirect To post Controller Session Will Destroy And Cant Use In Post Controller, I Don't Know How To Explain

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
class Post extends CI_Controller
{
public function index()
{

    $login = $this->session->userdata('islogin'); // $login will be 1 

    if($login)
    {
        $data = array (
            'name' => 'Hello',
        );
        $this->load->view('post/index',$data);
    }
    else {
        redirect('login/index');
    }

}
}
```

Comment: That Doesn't Work, The Problem Is Session Doesn't Save In Browser And I Don't Know What To Do

Comment: your session is stored in database